# Woocommerce. Max weight per order based on shipping class

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to set maximum weight 125kg per order but only for products with shipping class named "sypkie". I have code bellow and it works, but for all products in cart. I want to make it work only for products with "sypkie" shipping class.

```
add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items','check_cart_weight');

function check_cart_weight(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $weight = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight;
    if( $weight > 20 ){
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'You have %sKg weight and we allow only 20Kg of weight per order.', 'woocommerce' ), $weight ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

How to modify this code to work with shipping class?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items','check_cart_weight');
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'check_cart_weight' );

function check_cart_weight()
    {
    $cart = WC()->cart;
    if(!$cart) return;
    $weight = 0;
    foreach($cart->get_cart_contents() as $item)
        {
        if(!isset($item['product_id'])) continue;
        $prod = wc_get_product($item['product_id']);
        if($prod->get_shipping_class()!=='sypkie') continue;
        $weight += ($item['quantity'] * (float)$prod->get_weight());
        };
    if( $weight > 125 )
        {
        $error =  sprintf( __( 'You have %sKg weight and we allow only 125Kg of weight per order.', 'woocommerce' ), $weight);
        if(is_checkout()) { wc_add_notice($error, 'error'); } else { wc_print_notice($error, 'error'); };
        };
    }
```

This goes through items in the cart, checks their shipping class (matching by the **slug** of the shipping class) and adds their weight up. I've also added the same function to the action woocommerce_checkout_process which shows the same message on the checkout page.

Comment: Thank You! Works perfect!

Comment: Thanx @manx! Would be great if you could check the answer as accepted.